# JS: how to check array of integers for corresponding negative integer?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given a (JS) array of integers, I am trying to ascertain if it is zer0-balanced -- that is, for any element x there is a corresponding element of -x - *in a single line of code*.

I would think you could do this using `every()` and `includes()` but can't quite get the right logic.

`arr.every(n => arr.includes(-n))` obviously does not work because `includes()` is not a function, but that's the idea I've been failing least with.  where to take this next?  thank you!

Comment: You can write anything in JavaScript in one line by removing all line breaks. That's a useless requirement.

Comment: [`Array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a function, but must be called in an environment that supports ES2016. This can be swapped out for `.indexOf()`. `arr.every(n => ~arr.indexOf(-n))`

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. The array `[1, 1, -1]` has the property that for every element x there is a corresponding element -x, but it isn't zero-balanced. Which do you actually need? Why does it have to be a single line of code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and count with increment with positive numbers and decrement with negative numbers. If done, check all properties and return the nefgated check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function isBalanced(array) {
    var hash = {};
    array.forEach(a => hash[Math.abs(a)] = (hash[Math.abs(a)] || 0) + Math.sign(a));

    return !Object.keys(hash).some(k => hash[k]);
}

console.log(isBalanced([1, 2, -2, -1]));
console.log(isBalanced([1, 2, -2, -1, -1, 1]));
console.log(isBalanced([1, 2, -2]));
console.log(isBalanced([1, 2, -2, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this is question has been asked numerous times over the years, the statement "obviously does not work because includes() is not a function" leads me to believe that the OP is not running this in an environment that supports ES2016 features.

Comment: that's very cool.  could you explain const checkNegative = (n, _, a) => a.includes(-n) works and const checkNegative = (n, a) => a.includes(-n) doesn't?

Comment: it is the callback structur which is at the first place the element, then comes the actual index and then tha calling array. theat is the reason why it does not work with index, but with array.

Comment: @mhodges, arrow function indicates ES6.

Comment: @DCR 3 parameters get passed to the `.every()` callback. the element, the index, and the original array. Nina labeled these as n, _, and a, but they can be named anything - it's order that matters.

Comment: @NinaScholz ES6 !== ES2016

Comment: @mhodges, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment has `Array.every` but not `Array.includes`, that's strange, but you can use `Array.some` instead of includes like so

```
arr.every(n => arr.some(x => x === -n))
```

Comment: This will accept `[1, 1, -1]` and it isn't clear if OP wants to accept that array.

Comment: That was my thought before I posted this too, but given that OP was intending on using the function 'includes', which would produce that behavior, I thought it was appropriate.

Comment: the error thrown for this line of code in my console is the same as for `every()`  -- "Uncaught TypeError: n.some is not a function"

Comment: If you google each of these javascript functions, you can find polyfills that you can copy and paste into your .js files

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `every` with `indexOf` and a reduce statement to check if entire array actually sums up to zero as first pre-condition.

Using `console.log`, you can see it happen for every item in array in console.

If it does not find a matching negative element at any point, it stops execution there.

```js
const arr = [1, 4, 8, -4, -8, -1,13,-13];
console.log((arr.reduce((x, y) => x + y) == 0) && arr.every(n => {console.log(n); return arr.indexOf(-n) > -1; }));
```